# What is the exact age of Tamiz (التمییز) for children?

Tags: children, age

I have heard that it is better for men and women to observe some items or rulings (Ahkam) in front of the children who are at the age of Tamiz (التمییز). According to my researches, the age of Tamiz is the age of the children who are not in the age of Bolugh (puberty) but are able to realize the difference between good and bad things.

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread8318.html)

But I did not find any precise number (age) about it. So what is the range of Tamiz age?

Comment: Tamiz is respect ryt?

Answer (score 2):

The realization of the issue is related to yourselves. It likewise related to the puberty premature and vice versa. In fact we can say that it depend upon the age of the puberty and it could have a straight relation between the age of the puberty of the child and the age of Tamiz.

Hence we cannot say a specific number (age).

Of course for instance we can say that a boy who is 11, then he could be Momayez (Tamiz). On the whole, as I mentioned above, there is not any precise number for it, but usually you can recognize from the apparent and the behaviour of the children.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.askquran.ir](http://www.askquran.ir/thread378.html)